# Got "Error limit reached" while trying to send email with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

I am getting "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Error limit reached" when I try to send the mail using C# code.

```
try
{
    MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();

    emailMessage.Subject = "smth subject";

    messages = string.Empty;

    string serverName = System.Environment.MachineName;
    string serverIpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)
                                .First(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();

    string serverNameWithDetails = Settings.Default.ServiceDisplayName + " (server's name: " + serverName + ", server's ip address: " + serverIpAddress + ")";

    emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    emailMessage.Body = "smth body";
    emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(config.SmtpUser);
    emailMessage.To.Add("myAddress@aaa.com");

    // Set encoding
    emailMessage.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    emailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(config.SmptHost, config.SmptPort);

    NetworkCredential smtpUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(config.SmtpUser, config.SmtpPassword);
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = smtpUserInfo;

    smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);

    EmailSent = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.ErrorFormat("The following error occured while building and sending the email: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

So the e.Message is the error written above, but I just can not find any information about this error message.
It enters the catch section when the `smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);` line is executed.
Can anyone help me?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Error limit reached

Gets fired if you are trying to send large amounts of emails - sounds logic right :-)

The tricky part is that the limits can be very low for some ISPs (20 - 500 different mails/hour), and if you declare the sender as an email that's not registered, on the mail server, the limit can be 0, and then trigger this kind of error message.

My point being: Use an email registered on the mail server, and be aware of the limits, that in some cases can be reached just by running your code while you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try thiz..

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail; 
string to = strSidMail;
string from = "rajeeshmenoth@wordpress.com";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = txt_subject.text;
message.Body = mailbody;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new
System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourgmail id", "Password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = basicCredential1;   
try
{
client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
```

Comment: I changed the smtp password of the client and it seems that everything works fine. I don't know if I solved the issue, I will be attentive to the logs and I hope it will not happen again. Anyway, thanks for helping!